# Canvas image to blob, changing image size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that scales an image to fit inside of it, what I'm trying to do is export the image in a larger size than what the canvas is set to. I am using the canvas.toBlob method to get the blob data and am sending that to my server as an uploaded file.

For example, the canvas is 350px by 350px, I'd like to save the image as 800px by 1000px.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>

<script type="text/javasript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            var img_info = { width:527, height:350 };
            var sourceX = 0;
            var sourceY = 150;
            var sourceWidth = 4520;
            var sourceHeight = 3000;
            var destWidth = img_info.width;
            var destHeight = img_info.height;
            var destX = canvas.width / 2 - destWidth / 2;
            var destY = canvas.height / 2 - destHeight / 2;

            context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
        };

    imageObj.src = 'hhttp://i.imgur.com/tKplLLb.jpg';

    canvas.toBlob(
        function (blob) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blob);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {

                }
            });
       },
     'image/jpg'
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use drawImage to scale the image to a second, hidden canvas and use toBlob on the result?

Comment: @Gaurav not a bad idea, going to give that a try to see if it keeps the same aspect ratio

Answer (score 9):

This function takes a canvas and width+height parameters. It will return a new canvas element on which you can call `toBlob`

```
function getResizedCanvas(canvas,newWidth,newHeight) {
    var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    tmpCanvas.width = newWidth;
    tmpCanvas.height = newHeight;

    var ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,0,0,newWidth,newHeight);

    return tmpCanvas;
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/L4dua/

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up implementing Guarav's suggestion. I +1 your answer

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me combined with vue-advanced-cropper for vuejs, i've used this for resize the canvas result of my first Circle Cropper